# svn get_log function

Tags: tortoisesvn

i want to retrieve all the revisions on one particular user so i am using getlog function.but the logentry for author variable returns test instead of computer name.why is it so?

Comment: Can you provide the full command you are using pls?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
svn log -q | grep "^r.* | username |" | cut -d"r" -f2 | cut -d" " -f1
```

This will printout the revision number for that particular user.

Comment: thanks.but i am writing it in a program.so hoe can i implement it in my code?

Comment: May be you can take a look at SVNKit.com where you have a full java library or you can call the command line from within your program.